# Using parametrized SQL staement to check substring

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm using `python MySQLdb`

Here's my line of code:

```
    cursor.execute("SELECT F_Title FROM Films WHERE F_Title LIKE  \"%%s%\"", [search])
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character '"' (0x22) at index 53
```

I'm trying to check id the `search` variable is a substring of any of the `F_Title` values

I've also tried:

```
... WHERE F_Title LIKE '%%s%'"

... WHERE CONTAINS(F_Title, '&s'")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If search is just one term, I think you want something like `"cursor.execute("SELECT F_Title FROM Films WHERE F_Title LIKE  \"%%%s%%\"" % search)` ?

Comment: This worked! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad it helped... Just if you're curious... That's because when you want to output a `%`, you need to escape it with another `%`, so it actually looks like `%%` (more here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations )